# C# RemoveAll with Generic Lists showing error

Tags: c#, delegates, removeall, dpll

I'm doing a SAT Solver (mainly the DPLL or Partial DPLL) and I have the method for Unit Propogation. Basically what it does is that it checks whether there are any standalone literals, and removes that literal, and any instance found in the other clauses. Any Example would be

```
(x) (x,y) (w,z)
```

the Unit Propogation would be 'x' and when performing the unit prop it would leave only `(w,z)`

In this method I have several nested `foreach` loops and `List<literals>` `<literals>` is a custom made class which has 2 variables `hasNegation` (bool) and char `literalCharacter`

The Coding is below, and will explain from below

```
       foreach (clauses c1 in listOfClauses)
       {
           if (c1.listOfLiterals.Count == 1)
           {
               literals l1 = c1.listOfLiterals[0];
               solved.Add(l1);

               foreach (clauses c2 in listOfClauses)
               {
                   List<literals> tempList = new List<literals>();

                   foreach (literals l2 in listOfLiterals)
                   {
                       if (l2.solveDPLL(l1))
                       {
                           removable.Add(c2);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           if (c2.listOfLiterals.Count == 1)
                           {
                               UNSAT = true;
                               return false;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               if (l1.solveDPLL(l2))
                               {
                                   tempList.Add(l2);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                       c2.listOfLiterals.RemoveAll(tempList); //obviously giving error
                   }

               }
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
```

I have 2 `List <literals>` which are `templist` and `listOfLiterals` where the LATTER is the "parent"

I am tryign to remove the entries of `listOfLiterals` that match with `tempList` and I use `c2.listOfLiterals.RemoveAll(tempList);` obviously will output an error as it is not a Delegate.

I've searched a lot,even on stackoverflow, but every one of them compares either to an ID or an integer. In my case, since I'm just comparing 2 `Lists`, how can I do the delegate so that, the entries that are the same in both listOfLiterals and tempList are removed from **listOfLiterals?**

Many thanks

---

EDIT:

Literals Class

```
    public class literals
{

    public char literalCharacter { get; set; }

    public bool negation { get; set; }
    public literals(char lc, bool neg )
    {
        literalCharacter = lc;
        negation = neg;
    }

    public bool solveDPLL (literals lit)
    {
        return ((Object.Equals(literalCharacter, lit.literalCharacter) && (negation == lit.negation)));
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return literalCharacter + " : " + !negation;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with using a little LINQ magic:

```
c2.listOfLiterals = c2.listOfLiterals.Except(tempList).ToList();
```

Or loop over the `tempList`:

```
foreach (var item in tempList)
{
    c2.listOfLiterals.Remove(item);
}
```

You may need your `literals` class to implement `IEqualityComparer<literal>` and then provide an implementation for `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. See the [MSDN page for `Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx) for a good example of this.

Comment: Does the `ToList` act like `ToArray()` or?

Comment: `Except()` returns  `IEnumerable<T>` and `ToList()` will convert it back to a `List<T>`.

Comment: Check, my edited Code.  I do not actually have the GetHashCode Method. in my case didn't need it

Comment: yeah I have SolveDPLL to Compare both Objects. Compares the one I am using, and the one I am passing to the method.

Comment: Worked like a charm. LINQ avoided me some trouble I guess